# Updating a dropdown via knockout and ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to update a dropdown using knockout and data retrieved via an ajax call. The ajax call is triggered by clicking on a refresh link.
The dropdown is successfully populated when the page is first rendered. However, clicking refresh results in clearing the dropdown instead of repopulating with new data.

Html:

```
<select data-bind="options: pages, optionsText: 'Name', optionsCaption: 'Select a page...'"></select> 
<a id="refreshpage">Refresh</a>
```

Script:

```
var initialData = "[{"Id":"231271443653720","Name":"Car2"},{"Id":"439319486078105","Name":"Electronics1.2"},{"Id":"115147185289433","Name":"Product"},{"Id":"145033098963549","Name":"Product2"}]";
var viewModel = {
    pages : ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData)
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);


$('#refreshpage').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetPageList", "FbWizard")",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.Success) {
                ko.mapping.updateFromJS(data.Data);
            } else {
                displayErrors(form, data.Errors);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Data from ajax call:

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "Data": "[{"Id":"231271443653720","Name":"Car2"},{"Id":"439319486078105","Name":"Electronics1.2"},{"Id":"115147185289433","Name":"Product"},{"Id":"145033098963549","Name":"Product2"}]"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are not telling the mapping plugin what to target. How is it suppose to know that the data you are passing is supposed to be mapped to the pages collection.

Here is a simplified version of your code that tells the mapping what target.

BTW The initialData and ajax result were the same so you wouldn't have noticed a change if it had worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/gkLgZ/

```
var initialData = [{"Id":"231271443653720","Name":"Car2"},{"Id":"439319486078105","Name":"Electronics1.2"},{"Id":"115147185289433","Name":"Product"},{"Id":"145033098963549","Name":"Product2"}];

var json = [{"Id":"231271443653720","Name":"Car2"},{"Id":"439319486078105","Name":"Electronics1.2"},{"Id":"115147185289433","Name":"Product"}];

var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    this.pages = ko.mapping.fromJS(initialData);

    this.refresh = function () {
         ko.mapping.fromJS(json, self.pages);
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

I removed the jquery click binding. Is there any reason you need to use a jquery click bind instead of a Knockout binding? It's not recommended to mix the two if possible, it dilutes the separation of concerns that KO is so good at enforcing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying your example but the jsfiddle code is broken in IE9. The dropdown does not populate or refresh.

Comment: @rboarman - This seems to be an IE9 jsfiddle issue. In IE9 the Knockout scripts coming from Github are being blocked because of a mime type mismatch. Nothing I can do to fix that. The code is sound though if you try it in Chrome/FF.

Comment: Your answer was essentially correct except that I needed to use ko.mapping.fromJSON() instead of ko.mapping.fromJS() to parse the data returned from the ajax call. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You only need to use fromJSON is you string isn't automatically parsed. If you are using jquery ajax and returning the correct headers then it should be preparsed to a json object before you get to the mapping stage.

Comment: That looks fine, it's pretty similar to the ajax call im using. The problem is most likely at your server side. Are you seeing application/json returned in your response headers?